# python+ pycuda (linux) error

Tags: python, pycuda

I've installed python+pycuda (and other libraries) through this link: http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Linux

But when I run test program, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_driver.py", line 17, in <module>
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/gpuarray.py", line 3, in <module>
import pycuda.elementwise as elementwise
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2014.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/elementwise.py", line 34, in <module>
from pytools import memoize_method
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2014.3.5-py2.7.egg/pytools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from six.moves import range, zip, intern, input
ImportError: cannot import name intern
```

- six is installed. I don't know what should I do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a OSX system I manage to solve the problem by upgrading the six package via pip. Namely
$ pip install six --upgrade

Answer (score 3):

I was seeing this exact same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 but didn't want to override Ubuntu's version of six due to lots of finicky dependency issues. I thought it was odd that the pytools version in the error message (**2014.3.5**) didn't match the version from the [Ubuntu apt repo (**2013.5.7**)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python/python-pytools).

It turns out that I had previously tried to install pycuda from source by checking out the git repository. I had also previously installed pip. Since pytools is listed as a requirement in pycuda's setup.py, pip installed its version of pytools (2014.3.5). And that's where the incompatibility between six and pytools originates.

To solve the issue, I uninstalled both pycuda and pytools using `pip remove pycuda pytools` and then installed pycuda using `apt-get` which then auto-installed the compatible version of pytools.

Just wanted to post this as an alternative solution in case anyone else prefers to keep the default Ubuntu version of six.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Ubuntu 14.04 but neither of the tips above worked. [This page](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issues/107/import-intern-module-from-sixmoves) recommends editing the file causing the error directly. So I edited `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools/__init__.py` and changed the line:

```
from six.moves import range, zip, intern, input
```

Into

```
try:
    from six.moves import range, zip, intern, input
except ImportError:
    from six.moves import range, zip, input
```

Not nice editing included library files, but it got around the error.